# Android emulator and AndEngine GLES2.0

Tags: android, andengine

Is there a problem with android's emulator because the application stops working whenever I try to open it with a version below android 4? I'm using AndEngine GLES2.0.

Comment: You mean API Version? GLES2.0 requires at least Android 2.2

Comment: make sure your android dev environment is the latest and greatest - not sure what you are using but check for updates